# Sqoop - Is it possible to import flat-files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, sqoop

I know that it is possible to import RDBM's data to HDFS via sqoop but I would like to know if it is possible to import flat-files as well.

For example, is it possible to import a file from a remote Linux filesystem ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you considered the use of Flume ? http://flume.apache.org/

Comment: @sudarshan Yes, but I really would like to know if it is possible with Sqoop

Answer (score 1):

For putting flat files in HDFS, Sqoop is not required and I don't see any reason for using Sqoop for this. Just try the below command. [Here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/hdfs_shell.html#put) is the documentation for the same.

```
hadoop fs -put <src-linux-file-system> <target-hdfs-file-system>
```

Comment: Thanks. But i would like to know the answer for Sqoop, for the case of a remote flat-file for example

Comment: Let us know why you want to use Sqoop and not an elephant :) and then others can help you.

Comment: I'm just studiying all the possibilities. In my project, we will use sqoop to import RDBM's data into hdfs. We thaught it will be easier to also use sqoop to import flat-files from remote sources. If it is not possible, we will of course study other possibilities.

Comment: We should always find a tool to meet the requirement not the other way - best of luck in finding an alternative.

Comment: @shanks_roux, If your host ( remote file system/source) has Hadoop client installed, then it would be able to read / write to HDFS. Using hadoop fs -put would be viable option.

Comment: This sounds a like trying to make sqoop do something it was not meant to do, go with the elephant :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no to import flat text files using sqoop,use Flume to import

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop cannot be used to import any file type into Hadoop. Depending on your requirements for timeliness of data ingestion into hadoop (batch, near real-time, real-time) you can choose from fs -put (good for macro batches), flume or kafka (good for more frequent updates like near real-time use cases). For real-time ingestion, you may need to consider about memory first, then permanent storage second. In this case you may need to use some tools like storm or spark streaming.